# Relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have just connected Powerbuilder with PostgreSQL through ODBC, but something goes wrong when I'm trying to create a datawindow! I can't understand where is the problem. I will be so grateful to receive any answers.

***The error:***

> ```
> Cannot create DataWindow
>
> SQLSTATE=42P01
> ERROR:relation "core sample" does not exist;
>
> No query has been executed with that handle
>
> SELECT CORE_SAMPLE.N_CORE,      CORE_SAMPLE.DEPTH,
>
> CORE_SAMPLE.WELL_ID_WELL,   CORE_SAMPLE.ID_CORE FROM 
>
> CORE_SAM'
> ```

Comment: Your error message doesn't make a lot of sense. The query doesn't match the message. Did you copy that verbatim? Also, as always: version numbers of your software.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I almost didn't work with these both programs, that's why I have such problems( And yes, I copied this verbatim. PostgreSQL 9.2, PowerBuilder 10.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, there is a mixup with names. `"core sample"` is not the same as `CORE_SAMPLE`. Hard to say more, based on what little information we have here.

[Unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in PostgreSQL, so `CORE_SAMPLE`, `Core_Sample` or `core_sample` end up to be identical.
But once you enclose identifiers in double quotes, the name is preserved as is. This way you can have otherwise illegal characters like a space in the name: `"core sample"`. My standing advise is to stay away form that and use legal, lower case identifiers exclusively with PostgreSQL.

The error message tells you there is no table named `"core sample"`, at least not in the database you connected to in any of the schemas listed in the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777).
But the displayed query refers to a table named `CORE_SAMPLE` which does not match this error message.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!Simple rewriting CORE_SAMPLE in core_sample solved my problem. =)

Comment: @user2423106: Nice! If that solved your problem, consider accepting the answer.