# Different result when calling a stored procedure from pgadmin and from doctrine ORM

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, plpgsql, pgadmin

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_network()
    RETURNS inet AS
$BODY$
/* get the next networkd */
DECLARE 
      ip inet;
BEGIN
      select into ip (inet'10.41.142.0' + nextval('NetworkAddress_seq'));
  return ip;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

the sequence NetworkAddress_seq increments with 256:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "NetworkAddress_seq"
    INCREMENT 256
    MINVALUE 256
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    START 256
    CACHE 256;
    ALTER TABLE "NetworkAddress_seq"
    OWNER TO my_user;
```

When I call the function from pgAdmin I get: `10.41.143.0`

When I call it from php/Doctrine/ORM:

```
$stmt = $this->_em->getConnection()->prepare("select get_next_network()");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetchColumn(0);
```

I get something like `10.56.142.0`

Why?

Edit:
I checked that I'm using the same procedure by hardcoding the return value - in this case I get the same value both in pgadmin and in php. This also puts the question mark on the sequence but as I'm querying it from the procedure and not directly I would assume that no matter from where I call the get_next_network procedure it will use the same sequence... or am I wrong about this?

Edit2:
The strange behavior is not related to the php side - I get the same strange results if
open multiple pgAdmin SQL query windows (different DB connections?). For example: in Window1 I run

```
select * from get_next_network();
```

end get: 10.43.143.0
and if I run it again I get: 10.43.144.0, 10.43.145.0, ... etc.
In Window2 - the same query returns: 10.44.143.0 and all the subsequent queries get:
10.44.144.0, 10.44.145.0,..etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the CACHE setting to 256. I removed it (default 1) and now no matter from where I call my procedure I get the next value..

An explanation from [here](http://linuxfinances.info/info/postgresql.html)

> In the case of PostgreSQL, a sequence object can be configured to cache multiple values within a single backend process so that if you are generating large numbers of values, a particular backend might " lay claim" to a range of 100 values all at once, making clashes between concurrent processes go away.
>
> A disadvantage to cacheing is that values can and will get skipped along the way. If you were expecting them to fall in some exact serial order, that expectation will fail.

I was expecting that each call to the procedure will grow the sequence with the increment no matter from where it was executing.

Answer (score 2):

Situations like these usually point to that your are not connecting to the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

Next to a possible confusion with the database connection like hinted by @Marek, there is another typical pitfall:

A different setting for the [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777), which could resolve `'NetworkAddress_seq'` to a SEQUENCE of the same name in a different schema, or even find a function `get_next_network()` in a different schema.

```sql
  select into ip (inet'10.41.142.0' + nextval('NetworkAddress_seq'));
```

BTW, I *never* use CaMeL-case identifiers in Postgres. [That's just asking for trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763736/relation-does-not-exist/16763963#16763963).

The call `nextval('NetworkAddress_seq')` looks for a sequence with CaMeL-case name, created with:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE "NetworkAddress_seq";  -- with double-quotes!
```

But not:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE NetworkAddress_seq;
```

.. which results in a sequence named `networkaddress_seq`, and you would have to use:

```sql
nextval('networkaddress_seq')
```

May be part of the problem.

---

Also, everything might be correct and the sequence has been incremented that many times in between. You ruled that out, right?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify why I'm sure that I'm using the same get_next_network() function. Using a different sequence should be impossible as long as I'm not querying the sequence directly but from the procedure - and I would assume that no matter from where I call the procedure it will always use the same sequence.

Comment: @tudor: That's not correct: `Using a different sequence should be impossible`. Object names take the current `search_path` into account. You can save the `search_path` with the function, though. See point 5. of my [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777).