# I can't insert data from text boxes into postgre sql table using C#

Tags: c#, postgresql-9.3

and here is my code

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
        NpgsqlConnection conn;
        NpgsqlCommand cmd;
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeData"].ConnectionString;
        private DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = false;
        }


        string employee = "insert into  VSP_Employee values ('" + txtEmpid.Text + "','" + txtEmpname.Text + "','" + txtEmailid.Text + "','" + txtphnum.Text + "','" + txtDOB.Text + "','" + txtDOJ.Text + "','" + txtNOD.Text + "','" + txtSalary.Text + "','" + txtLeavestaken.Text + "','" + txtLeavesBalance.Text + "')";
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(employee, conn);
        cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(employee, conn);
        da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the DBMS in question but it looks like you're not creating the conn object and you're initializing da twice before using it. Check that stuff first and then add more error detail to your question if it's not working.

Comment: And what's the result? Error message? Do you mean `vsp_employee` or `"VSP_Employee"`?

Comment: i have even tried "VSP_Employee" but of no use @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: Thank You very much - @IanGilroy.  when i tried to execute the above program i have got the following error                                       ."Npgsql.NpgsqlException:                                             relation "vsp_employee" doesnot exist                                 severity:error                                                           code:42P01                                                          Can u please help me in solving this.......... THANKING YOU

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: The relation does not exist. There are many similar question with loads of answers here. [Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763736/relation-does-not-exist/16763963#16763963)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... I have already cross checked both the names given are same.... no change same error@ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: Have you considered that you might be connecting to the wrong database?

Comment: i have checked again.. i have connected to the correct database only.....

Comment: Any solution for my problem................@ErwinBrandstetter